# Bootstrap 3 - how to space 3 centered columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

Hi I would like to reach this output with bootstrap 3.7:

Assume boxes are :

1.) **centered** in row

2.) equal in size

3.) equal spacing between them.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div id="header" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 codexBox"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4 codexBox"></div>
            <div class="col-md-4 codexBox"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I would happily adjoin my SCSS yet after so many trials from margins, col wrappers, paddings first/last :not I couldn't find a **viable** solution that would 'hold water', as the expression goes.

**Flex** would be happily consumed here as long as it would be responsive through bootstrap grid cols.

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.minimit.com/demos/bootstrap-3-responsive-centered-columns

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flexbox: center horizontally and vertically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026884/flexbox-center-horizontally-and-vertically)

Comment: Consider the given answer, which were deleted, did exactly what you asked, you should explain better what the expected outcome should be. Both relative to the row and viewport, as the now 3 images doesn't say much